# Как rand в C принимает отрицательные значения в интервале?

Tags: c

Как понять смысл конструкции

```
rand() % 21 + (-10)
```

Не понятно значение (-10), т.е. здесь значение интервала до 21, но почему -10 указана в скобках и работает ли rand с отрицательными числами в интервале?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

функция `rand()` выдаёт значение от 0 до 2^15 - 1 (32767)

`rand() % 21`
вычисляет остаток от деления полученного случайного числа на 21 (т.е. от 0 до 20).

поскольку остатки цикличны таким образом реализуется генерация случайного числа от 0 до 20 включительно

`+ (-10)`
смещает случайное число влево на 10, т.е. вместо случайного числа в диапазоне 0..20 получается случайное число в диапазоне -10..10

P.S.

если бы требовалось не целочисленное значение, а действительное, то можно было бы сделать так:

```
float value = -10.0f + 20 * float(rand()) / 32767.0
```

P.S.

на счет `32767` я уже помню слабо, вроде можно было бы использовать константу `RND_MAX` или что-то такое

Comment: 1) Функция `rand()` выдаёт значения от `0` до [`RAND_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/RAND_MAX), и `32767` — это минимальное допустимое значение `RAND_MAX`. На практике оно запросто может быть [немного больше](https://ideone.com/6mucM8). 2) `float value = -10.0f + 20 * float(rand()) / 32767.0` Три константы в выражении и все имеют разный тип: `float`, `int` и `double`. Какое-то неконсистентное выражение...

Answer (score 2):

Первая часть даёт диапазон случайных чисел 0..20, а вычитание десятки переводит его в диапазон -10..10

Answer (score 1):

Этот код возвращает случайное значение в интервале от `-10` до `10`.